# New controls not recognized in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I added a couple of fields manually in my ASPX page which is actually holding a `FormView`. By manually, I mean by directly typing code in the `Markup` editor.

Now when I'm trying to access those controls in the code behind, nothing comes up in intellisense.

I deleted the `designer.cs` file and right clicked the ASPX page and chose `Convert to web application`, still no go.

The designer file's got the `FormView` control defined alright, but nothing about its child controls.

Do I really need to use `FindControl` to get this working ? Tell me if you need some code posted because at the moment maybe I'm just a bit confused about ASP.NET is actually working (or not at this moment).

Here's the markup code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="WebForm_PatientForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAppWalkthrough.WebForm_PatientForm" Title="Employee form" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:FormView ID="PatientForm" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Patient Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PatientName" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FullName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Patient ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PatientID" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("patientid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Eligibility
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Eligibility" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("service_executive_eligibility") %>' >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="N/A" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="No" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"  OnCommand="UpdatePatientInfo" Text="UpdateInfo" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("patientid") %>'>Update</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnCommand="CancelEditPatient" CommandName="CancelUpdate" Text="CancelInfo">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Employee First Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Employee Last Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Email address:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Work phone number:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="FormViewHeader">
                        Eligibility
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Eligibility">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="No" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server"  OnCommand="AddEmployee" Text="Add Employee">Add</asp:LinkButton>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```

Even if I add the controls manually in the designer file, I get a null reference error in the code behind at run time (even if intelisense picks up `FirstName` the object is null at runtime).

**EDIT**: I will try installing VS2010 SP1 and [this hotfix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/03/05/hotfix-for-issue-with-auto-generated-designer-files-not-adding-controls.aspx) I found and post the results.

**EDIT 2**: So I installed VS2010 SP1 which didn't solve the issue. I could not install the hotfix as my system is x64.

So I ditched VS2010 and tried with VS2013, which still doesn't pickup the markup controls.

Even `Page.FindControl("ControlName")` returns `null`. Something is very rotten with that webpage or VS2013...

Thanks.

Comment: Typically there's no need to go through all that.  if you type in control codes into the aspx and intellisense doesn't pick it up all you have to do is open the .aspx file, switch from code view to design view (and sometimes back to code view), and that is usually enough for Visual Studio to generate the appropriate code-behind in the .designer.cs file.

Comment: @DavidStratton Did that too, no go.

Comment: You may try cleaning the solution, and build solution again.

And, make sure you've ID for every controls you added manually.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath did that as well. No go. I even opened in in VS2013, no go still.

Comment: Usually I go to design view, add a button control from the Toolbox, double click it (which auto-generates the code to handle the button_click event in your code-behind), and then proceed to delete said code, and said button. Works for me almost every time, but these situations are tricky.

Comment: paste what you get when you do a "view source" in your browser.

Comment: Which part of your did you type yourself?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath Pretty much everything I'd say. I added the page, copied the first line from another page of the project for which intelisense is working fine and then added the 2nd line of directive to be able to communicate with the master page.

Comment: I think you need to findControl because they are inside of editTemplates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a problem that seems similar with Telerik UI components for WebForms before. I wanted to access items that were defined inside of a template in a grid, but unfortunately the only way to do that was to dig into child elements of that grid. That inner elements were not present in the designer.cs file as well.
I am not sure about that, but it can be a common behavior of nested elements in WebForms.

Comment: Yes, I'll stop expecting VS to abide by its (broken) best practices of using `ControlName.Property` and use `FormView.FindControl` instead.